# Set background color for only one pane in multi-pane Highstock chart

Tags: colors, highcharts

In this example: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume, is there a way to set the background color of the second pane?

For example, if you add `plotBackgroundColor: '#FCFFC5'` to the chart definition, then both panes become yellow.

Is it possible to make only the second (lower) pane yellow?

Comment: Ended up customizing the plotBackground code in the Highcharts source, which wasn't too bad.  Added a new offset param to calculate the rect that gets filled.

Comment: You can set only background for chart because it is only second yaxis, not separate chart.

Answer (score 2):

it's possible to change the background color for a specific range in your second pane using plotBands.

e.g. 
yAxis : {[
...
plotBands : {color : '#f7d724', from : -50, to : 50},
...
]}