# Background color for multiple Highchart panes, in Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I am using Highcharts in a Vue app by using [highcharts-vue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#readme)

I am setting my template like so

```
<highcharts class="vessChart" ref="chart" style="width:100%"  :callback="chartcallback" :options="options"    ></highcharts>
```

and then I set the options of the chart in the Vue

```
            yAxis:[],
        series:[],     
        background:[],
        options: {              
          chart: {
            borderWidth: 1,
            marginLeft: 40,
            marginRight: 2,
            type:'line',
            zoomType: 'x',
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            panning:true
            /*backgroundColor:'lightgrey'*/
          },
          title: {
            text: ''
          },
          pane:{
            background:[]
          },
          time:{
            useUTC:true
          },  
          credits:{
            enabled:false
          },
          tooltip: {
            shared: true
          },
          title:{
            text:null
          },
          rangeSelector: {
            inputEnabled: false
          },
          xAxis:{
            type:'datetime',
            title:
            {
              align:'high'
            }, 
            labels: {
              padding: 50,
              format: '{value:%e %b %Y}',
              style: {
                fontSize: '10px'
              }
            },
            crosshair: {
                enabled: true,
                width: 2,
                color: '#000'
            },
          },
          yAxis: [],   
          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              animation: false
            }
          },
          ,series: []
        }
```

and then, when I have data to add, I push data to yAxis, series and background arrays accordingly

```
                this.data.titles.forEach(title => {
              this.yAxis.push(
                  {
                    title: {
                      text: title.title,
                      margin:20,
                      fontSize:"15px"
                    },
                    labels: {
                      enabled:true,
                      align: 'left',
                      padding:15
                    },
                    alignTicks:'left', 
                    textAlign:'left',
                    align:'middle',
                    height: chartHeight+'%',
                    top:topStep+'%',
                    opposite:false, 
                    offset:0
                  }
              );
              this.background.push({backgroundColor: "red"});
              topStep = topStep + chartHeight + 5; 
              this.series.push({
                    yAxis:counter,
                    name:title.title,
                    data:[]
              });
              counter++;
            });//foreach 
            this.options.yAxis = this.yAxis;
            this.options.series = this.series;
            this.options.pane = this.background;
```

I tried to import highcharts-more by doing

```
    import highchartsmore from './highcharts-more.js'
```

but it does not work, the page comes back white.  I also tried to import it by going to index.html of Vue and adding `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>`

There is no error in the page, but still the panes have no color.

*If this is not possible, can I at least add a line between the panes somehow?

Thanks

EDIT

The red areas are the "panes" . Thanks[image]

Comment: Its hard to debug it like this. If you can provide a fiddle with your code that would be helpful.

Comment: Please reproduce your code on the online which I could work on. Here is a template which you can use: https://codesandbox.io/s/nw750l07nj

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Check this . If you remove the pane-related code and press "Update chart", should bring new data. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-40b4z

Comment: I am afraid that this demo doesn't work well. Could you fix it?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Hi again. Please check this out [https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-m6fse](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-m6fse) now it woks. When you hit the Update chart button, it creates 2 different panes in the same chart. Now, I want those 2 panes to have a background color somehow. Thanks

Comment: Use the this.chartOptions.chart.backgroundColor instead of this.chartOptions.pane.backgroundColor path. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-pt9jp

Comment: @SebastianWędzel This is the easy part. How can I have the panes itself have white color and the highchart still have black background ? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **chart.plotBackgroundColor** property to achieve your requirements.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-pt9jp

And because your chart is rendered dynamically, I encourage to disable animation:

```
chart: {
  type: "spline",
  title: "Hassaan",
  animation: false
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.plotBackgroundColor

Comment: This close, but not what I want. I want the panes to be white and the background to still be black.

Comment: I don't understand - do you have an image which will describe how the chart should looks like?

Comment: Check my original question, I uploaded an image, the red areas are the panes. Those panes must have a different color on their own.

Comment: So would you like to achieve something like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-umuhv

Comment: Yes, but you cannot see where one pane starts and the other ends. So the space between them, should also be black, so you can easily tell them apart. The space between 7.5 and 0

Comment: I see. Thank you for clarify it. I think that you can use the SVGRenderer.rect tool to render this part which should be hidden. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-umuhv

Answer (score 2):

For what I see you'll need to do styling by css [Docs page](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css), there is a live example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/css/chart-plotarea/)

```css
@import 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css';

.highcharts-plot-background {
 fill: #efffff;
}
.highcharts-plot-border {
 stroke-width: 2px;
 stroke: #7cb5ec;
}
```

Edit: 
I found a workaorund on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739263/set-background-color-for-only-one-pane-in-multi-pane-highstock-chart) topic, you can change the background color for a specific range pane using plotBands:

```
e.g. yAxis : {[ ... plotBands : {color : '#f7d724', from : -50, to : 50}, ... ]}
```

In your case you should set the values for the first and last ones.

Comment: This is closer to what I want, but I want the pane to have a different color and I cannot see any css rule for just the panes of the chart. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by pane, but I found [this](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/pane.background.backgroundColor) property on API Reference

Comment: Check the photo in my original question, the red areas are the panes. Thanks

Comment: I tried `pane:{
                  background:{
                    backgroundColor:"#000000"
                  }
                }` Inside the chart options json and inside the "chart" of the same options and it did nothing....

Answer (score 0):

A hackish way to do it would be to inject a rect into the svg.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-root")[0].innerHTML += '<rect width="100%" x="0" y="40" height="150" fill="#ff0000"></rect>';
document.getElementsByClassName("highcharts-root")[0].innerHTML += '<rect width="100%" x="0" y="200" height="150" fill="#ff0000"></rect>';
```